# Printing array partially in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am a newbie to C and want to print some special elements of an array.

```
//Partial code here
    char aaa[18] ;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 18) {
        aaa[i] = '#' ;
        printf("%c", aaa[i]) ;
        i = i + 4 ;    
   }
```

It's supposed to prints 4 `#` of aaa[0] ,aaa[4],aaa[8],aaa[12],aaa[16]. But it is not. It is printing them in a row like `#####`. But I don't want those .

Comment: you need to include a newline character - printf("%c\n", aaa[i]);    also, it is a good idea to get into the habit of calling variables, such as arrays, something that describes their purpose.  'aaa' isn't self-describing.

Comment: Replace with `printf("%c  " , aaa[i] ) ;` It will add space between array elements and If you need newline use `printf("%c \n" , aaa[i] ) ;`

Comment: I don't want to print them in a new line. I want to print them in different  places . The thing is , it prints them consecutively . this is the problem

Comment: @Mohammad What do you mean , you want to print them at diff places?

Comment: Do you want three spaces between them? Then you can use `"%c    "` as your format string.

Comment: what is your expected output ??

Comment: Can you display how you want # character to be printed?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I already mentioned that but apparently this is not what he needed.

Comment: yeah , but not with making space . I mean I want to print these array's cells . aaa[0] then aaa[4] and so on . per 4 cell , one of them should be printed .

Comment: @rootTraveller No, I think by diff places he means a hash at 0, 4, 8, 12 i.e. with 3 spaces between them. I wrote the format string with 3 spaces after %c. But SO just removed that.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya **But SO just removed that. ** :D :D

Comment: Sorry for this bad explanation . Look I'm gonna use counter to to change the places should be printed . Am I obvious ?

Comment: @Mohammad do you want the strings aaa[0], aaa[4] also to be printed? Can you just show the sample output?

Comment: @Mohammed, is your desired output like: "#ell# Wo#ld!#"?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to eventually print a string and get output like this

```
"#   #   #   #   #  "
```

minus the quotes.

You can do this by filling in a null-terminated string and then `printf`ing that, like so:

```
// +1 for space for a null terminator
// = {0}; fills the array with 0s
char aaa[18+1] = {0};

// for loop is more idiomatic for looping over an array of known size
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i += 4) {
    // if the remainder of dividing i by 4 is equal to 0
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        // then put a '#' character in the array at aaa[i]
        aaa[i] = '#';
    } else {
        // otherwise put a ' ' character in the array at aaa[i]
        aaa[i] = ' ';
    }
}

printf("%s", aaa);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you're adding 4 to the i variable in each cycle you're printing the positions 0, 4, 8, 12, 16 of the array consecutively.

If you want to print the vector with # as the 4*nth element you should do something like:

```
while( i < 18 ) 
{
  if( i % 4 == 0 )
  {
    aaa[i] = '#';
    printf("%c" ,aaa[i]);
  }
  else 
    printf(" "); // Assuming you want a space in between prints

  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . Yes I wanted this . or something like this . Thank you all ! But there is another tiny problem . I want to clear aaa[0] when I'm printing aaa[4] . But when I use    system("cls") , everything start from beginning .what can I do? It's you kindness to help me with this .